# Calling Activity from other activity leading to black screen

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

```
        val callIntent = Intent(this, AcsActivity::class.java)
        //callIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
        callIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP or  Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS)
        startActivity(callIntent)
        finish()
```

After hitting this code, screen turns black, if I see this app in recent apps it shows the right UI.

Called Activity:

```
class AcsActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_acs)
    }
}
```

Called Activity UI

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="org.jio.meet.conference.view.activity.AcsActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Called Activity manifest entry:

```
        <activity android:name="org.jio.meet.conference.view.activity.AcsActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"/>
```

Calling activity manifest entry:

```
        <activity
            android:name="org.jio.meet.dashboard.view.activity.StartMeetingActivity"
            android:configChanges="locale|orientation|screenSize"
            android:label=""
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
```

Am not sure what is wrong here, can you please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using flags `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` and `FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS` will hide the current already running activity. So, a black screen is shown.

According to Android document for [Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS) :

> If set, the new activity is not kept in the list of recently launched activities.

According to Android document for [Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP) :

> If set, and the activity being launched is already running in the current task, then instead of launching a new instance of that activity, all of the other activities on top of it will be closed and this Intent will be delivered to the (now on top) old activity as a new Intent.

You can't use flag for starting an Activity if not require some special features.

If you using `<item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>`, a default Theme for activity is shown with black screen aka 'Preview'.

You should set the window background to a color other than transparent. And the problem will be resolved without setting background in xml file.

Comment: I removed the flags but still the same issue. Issue is resolved when I put the background as white in the xml file.
    android:background="@color/White"

Do you understand what could be the issue here?

Comment: have you changed anything in your AppTheme?

Comment: @TarunChawla in AppTheme, Do you use `android:windowBackground` or same thing?

Comment: <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>, it is set to transparent. @Tungken

Comment: @TarunChawla You should set the window background to a color other than transparent. And the problem will be resolved without set background in xml file.

Comment: ok this will solve the issue but how transparent color makes it black?

Comment: Because a default Theme for activity is shown with black screen aka 'Preview' when you `android:windowBackground` to transparent.

Comment: @Tungken can you please edit your answer to reflect this, I would accept it then. Thank you!

Comment: @TarunChawla I edited the answer as your request.